# Can you drop a chest key for another player to pick up?

Tags: dungeon-defenders-2

Dungeon Defenders 2 changed the way their currency works.  Instead of everyone sharing all the chests on a map, as the first game did, There are keys given to players to unlock the chests. The wiki describes it like so:

> If there are 4 players each player will get 2 keys and each chest will only provide half the mana of a normal chest in that map. If there are 2 players both have 4 keys giving half of the mana each chest would.

Rather than have to go to every chest and then drop all the mana later for a builder, can I just give them my keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys are no longer a mechanic used to open mana chests. Instead, each player is allotted a certain amount of green mana when opening mana nodes. The amount of green mana you receive depends on the map and how many players you are playing with.

If you want to share mana with other players, press <kbd>M</kbd> to drop 10 mana, or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to drop all your mana.

Comment: No way to waive your chests and have that mana divide amongst the other players?

Comment: Nope, not unless you leave the game without opening the mana mode. Doing so redistributes the mana from your node to everyone else.